# at Wordpress Gravity Form plugin, how to customize the File Upload UI?

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, gravity-forms-plugin

everyone.

The gravity form plugin is using standard File Input Element.
[image]

I can make it looks like the custom UI by adding custom css into **File** label tag and using the **gform_field_content** filter.

after that, how can I display the imputed file name like the following status?

[image]

as you see, the imputed filename **Group 386.svg** is showing.

how can I do this? or is there any other good way?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.

I added the custom style to label by following this guide (W3 Custom File Upload
) https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms_custom.asp

after that, I added the js event to display the selected filename like the following.

```
// contat form, join us form
// customize file upload
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function () {
    jQuery('.contact-form__form input[type=file], .join-us__form input[type=file]').on('change', function () {
      const fileName = jQuery(this).val().split('\\').pop()
      jQuery('label', jQuery(this).parent().parent()).html(fileName)
    })
  })
})
```